# How can I modify this html file in python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to modify an html file, so the tag font contains the text i want to modify

```
<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial">
          PAT-204635 - LAICHE AHMED ILYES - Number 4
         </font>
```

The number changes from 1 to 128 so I decided to use for n in range loop like this (I used f at beginning of string for interpolation of n var):

```
old=d.findAll("font",{"color":"#FFFFFF"})
for n in range(129):
 for i in old:
  new=i.find(text=re.compile(f"PAT-204635 - LAICHE AHMED ILYES - Number {n}")).replace_with (f"PAT-204635 - LAICHE MOHAMED ISLAM - Number {n}")
  with open ("c:/users/dell/desktop/se2.html","wb") as ff:
   ff.write(d.prettify("utf-8"))
```

I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'NonType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'

I was able to alter the html file using the same way of iterating over variable old but I couldn't nest all of that inside the range loop, any ideas of how to do that or is there an easier way to modify?

Comment: Please fix your code's indentation.

Comment: @Ram fixed, do u know any good solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

When it throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'` error, this means that it couldn't find the string you wanted in the text so the `find()` function, returned `None` and absolutely `None` doesn't have `replace_with` attribute.
Do this to prevent the error:

```py
[...]
old=d.findAll("a",{"title":"Series"})
for n in range(129):
    for i in old:
        try:
            new=i.find(text=re.compile(f"PAT-204635 - LAICHE AHMED ILYES - Number {n}")).replace_with (f"PAT-204635 - LAICHE MOHAMED ISLAM - Number {n}")
        except:
            continue
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you want to  replace

> PAT-204635 - LAICHE AHMED ILYES - Number {n}

with

> PAT-204635 - LAICHE MOHAMED ISLAM - Number {n}

You can try this out.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
d = """
<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial">
          PAT-204635 - LAICHE AHMED ILYES - Number 4
         </font>
<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial">
          PAT-204635 - LAICHE AHMED ILYES - Number 56
         </font>
<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial">
          PAT-204635 - LAICHE AHMED ILYES - Number 9
         </font>
<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial">
          PAT-204635 - LAICHE AHMED ILYES - Number 77
         </font>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(d, 'lxml')
old = soup.findAll("font",{"color":"#FFFFFF"})
new= soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"PAT-204635 - LAICHE AHMED ILYES - Number \d+\b"))
for i in new:
    num = i.strip().split(' ')[-1]
    i = i.replace_with (f"PAT-204635 - LAICHE MOHAMED ISLAM - Number {num}")
        
print(soup.prettify())
```

This is how the final HTML code looks like.

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial">
   PAT-204635 - LAICHE MOHAMED ISLAM - Number 4
  </font>
  <font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial">
   PAT-204635 - LAICHE MOHAMED ISLAM - Number 56
  </font>
  <font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial">
   PAT-204635 - LAICHE MOHAMED ISLAM - Number 9
  </font>
  <font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial">
   PAT-204635 - LAICHE MOHAMED ISLAM - Number 77
  </font>
 </body>
</html>
```